# Vertically aligning a div with display flex and align-items center causes unintended offsets

Tags: html, css

I have this `html/css` snippet, and it is producing a "weird" output. Please run the code snippet.

```html
<div style="width: 100%; height: 100%; display: block;">
    <div style="border: 1px solid blue; margin-right: 15px; display: inline-block;">
        <h3>Centered</h3>
        <div style="background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3); width: 150px; height: 100px; display: block;">
            <div style="display: flex; align-items: center; width: 100%; height: 100%;">
                <h4 style="display: block;">First block</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="border: 1px solid green; margin-right: 10px; display: inline-block;">
        <h3>Default</h3>
        <div style="background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3); width: 150px; height: 100px; display: block;">
            <h4 style="display: block;">Second block</h4>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The root parent which is a `block` element, has two `inline-block` children. The first `inline-block` child has another child down the hierarchy that vertically centers it's content using `display:flex; align-items:center;`.

However, for some reason, this `align-item:center` is causing an offset at the top of the second child of the root parent. I mean, is this the expected behavior? How do I fix that offset issue. Sorry, I'm not so experienced with pure `html/css` and so your help will be appreciated. Thanks.